# How to get the ID of dynamically generated buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I auto genrated some buttons

```
    <div class="wrapper" id="wrapper"></div>
<script type="application/javascript">
    var x, i, y;
    for(i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
        y = i;
        x = "<button class=btn_class"+y+"id=btn"+y+"onclick(alert(this.id);>Ukor</button>";
        $("#wrapper").append(x);
    }

    $("button").on("click", function(){
        alert(this.id);
    });
</script>
```

I want to be perform different action when any of the  buttons are clicked.
but i can't seem to get get the buttons by id. I also need to send y as an arguement to the function

Comment: You need spaces around the attributes, and you should also put quotes around the values of the attributes. Otherwise, it's all one long attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have no spaces separating the attributes. So you're creating an element that looks like:

```
<button class=btnclass0id=btn0onclick(alert(this.id);>Ukor</button>
```

So everything is going into the `class` attribute. You should put quotes around the attribute values, and spaces between the attributes.

There's also no need for the `onclick` attribute, since you're using `$("button").on("click", ...)` to do that.

So it should be:

```
x = "<button class='btn_class"+y+"' id='btn"+y+"'>Ukor</button>";
```

You can also use jQuery's object-oriented way to create elements:

```
x = $("<button>", {
        "class": "btn_class" + y,
        "id": "btn"+y,
        text: "Ukor"
});
```

BTW, why do you put `y` in the class? Usually the point of classes is to have all the similar elements have the same class, so you can address them all at once.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, how do i send "y" as an argument to a function?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are building your HTML without the necessary spaces or punctuation between attributes, so your button HTML will look like this:

```
<button class=btn_class0id=btn0onclick(alert(this.id);>Ukor</button>
```

This means there is no `id` attribute.

Try fixing it up like this:

```
x = '<button class="btn_class' + y + '" id="btn' + y + '" onclick="alert(this.id);">Ukor</button>';
$("#wrapper").append(x);
```

...or better yet, use the jQuery API to build your DOM:

```
x = $('<button onclick="alert(this.id);">Ukor</button>').attr({
  id: 'btn' + y,
  className: 'btn_class' + y
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer, how do i pass "y" as an argument to a function using onclick()?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in the string formatting your code will generate

```
<button class=btnclass0id=btn0onclick(alert(this.id);>Ukor</button>
```

and you need:

```
<button class="btnclass0" id="btn0" onclick="alert(this.id);">Ukor</button>
```

```js
var x, i, y;
for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  y = i;
  x = "<button class='btn_class" + y + "' id='btn" + y + "'>Ukor</button>";
  $("#wrapper").append(x);
}

$("button").on("click", function() {
  alert(this.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper" id="wrapper"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the content into a single string and then append it once into the dom - faster than appending each iteration. Then using a designated click event handler - alert the id of the button. And the classes need to be a common value - not unique like the id's. Also - you don't need "y" at all and if you need to send the number to a function you have it already in the id - just get the numerical portion of the id and you can use it as required.

```js
   $(document).ready(function(){
  var x="";
    for(i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
       x += "<button class='btn_class' id='btn"+i+"'>Ukor</button> ";
      }

    $("#wrapper").append(x);

    $(document).on('click','.btn_class', function(){
      (alert($(this).attr('id')))
            })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper" id="wrapper"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use [**String template**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)  to avoid errors of spacing between attrs on concatenating -> Better in visibility of variables in String:

```js
   
        $(Array.from({length:11},(v,k)=>k)
          .map((i)=>`<button class="btn_class${i}" id="btn${i}" onclick="alert(this.id)">Ukor${i}</button>`)
          .join('')).appendTo('#wrapper')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper" id="wrapper"></div>
```